# How to reference files within a github repository

Tags: git, reactjs, github, github-pages

I have a Github repo where I would like to host a React.js app I wrote in the `docs` directory of the repo rather than using the `gh-pages` branch.  The `index.html` and `bundle.js` are built in the `dist` directory so I thought I would symlink the two files to the `docs` directory but apparently that does not work.  Does anyone know how I could reference the `bundle.js` and `index.html` stored in the `dist` directory to point to the `docs` directory on the master branch?

Comment: You can't. Github is not a file host. They intentionally prevent this by serving files as content type `text/plain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My point of view is more to update your build to output in the 'docs' folder. It makes more sense.

But a better solution (because that is not a good thing to do to commit built files with source files) is to use the 'gh-pages' branch by doing the very clever solution described here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/dcdcab0ecc86d9643bc9c3c9a9eee8bbad63bb43/template/README.md#github-pages

It should be run after your build. I copy the commands here (adapted for your `dist` folder) :

`git commit -am "Save local changes"`

`git checkout -B gh-pages`

`git add -f dist`

`git commit -am "Rebuild website"`

`git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter dist`

`git push -f origin gh-pages`

`git checkout -`

I use it and it works very well. That way only the last version built is commited and in its own branch, not polluting your source code...